# “Syntax error on token ”;“, , expected”

Tags: java, arrays

So I've been looking through a lot of different posts to try and fix this error and every solution that I've found hasn't helped me in the slightest. Basically in my code I am creating an Array of Fields (from my Field Class) and I get this error after the first line of code.

```
private Main.Fields[] fieldList = new Main.Fields[4];

// Fields;
fieldList= {
        Fields("Play", 1100, 700, 2);  
        Fields("Controls", 1100, 740, 2); 
        Fields("Exit", 1100, 780, 2);
        Fields("Welcome to the Game", 200, 400, 3);
};
```

If anyone can tell me what is wrong with it that would be great.

Comment: Change the semicolons on the end of the `Fields("Play", 1100, 700, 2);` to commas

Comment: To commas* I think you mean, which is what the error states. `{Fields(...), Fields(...), ... }`

Comment: Replace  ";" with "," in the array declaration

Answer (score 2):

You have combined two different formats for array declaration and initialization. You can do one of:

```
// Fields;
private Main.Fields[] fieldList = {
        new Main.Fields("Play", 1100, 700, 2),
        new Main.Fields("Controls", 1100, 740, 2), 
        new Main.Fields("Exit", 1100, 780, 2),
        new Main.Fields("Welcome to the Game", 200, 400, 3)
};
```

**or**

```
private Main.Fields[] fieldList = new Main.Fields[4];

// Fields;
{
        fieldList[0] = new Main.Fields("Play", 1100, 700, 2);
        fieldList[1] = new Main.Fields("Controls", 1100, 740, 2); 
        fieldList[2] = new Main.Fields("Exit", 1100, 780, 2);
        fieldList[3] = new Main.Fields("Welcome to the Game", 200, 400, 3);
}
```